# Публикация студенческих проектов на GitHub

Tags: github

Доброго времени суток,

Собираюсь опубликовать свои учебные проекты на GitHub, дабы соответствовать современным реалиям и будущие работодатели или те, кто будет во мне заинтересован как в соискателе позиции в сфере IT, могли составить обо мне какое-то впечатление?

По самому порталу нет вопросов, они - к лицензии, под которой их можно разместить. Стоит ли заморачиваться с авторскими правами на свои решения, если они чем-то особенным не выделяются, но при этом в душе ты желаешь, чтобы ими не пользовались в сомнительных целях, и если да, то какую выбрать?

Comment: Вам никто не мешает добавить файл License.md или прям в readme.md написать все, что Вы считаете нужным. Например, "используйте на свой страх и риск, ко мне претензий не предъявляйте, если хотите на этом сделать коммерческий продукт - поделитесь немного".

Comment: Прежде чем выбирать лицензию, нужно однозначно определиться, что такое «сомнительные цели» и иметь в виду, что это является дискриминацией по цели применения, то есть ваши проекты не будут являться свободным ПО (если опираться на определение от Open Source Initiative)

Comment: видел один раз - "не используйте для злых намерений".

Comment: @KoVadim ага, и из-за неё [GNU считает лицензию JSON несвободной](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#JSON)

Comment: то есть, GNU потакает злу... так и знал. Но зато, если какие то вирусы/малварь будет использовать json как основу протокола для обмена информации - можно судить по такой странной статье:)

Answer (score -1):

> Стоит ли заморачиваться с авторскими правами на свои решения, если они
> чем-то особенным не выделяются, но при этом в душе ты желаешь, чтобы
> ими не пользовались в сомнительных целях, и если да, то какую выбрать?

"Сомнительные действия" наказуемы сами по себе, вне зависимости от вида разрешения на творения, которые были использования при их совершении, хотя в некоторых разрешениях (англ: license), упоминается, что использование данного творения не обязывает его создателя отвечать за последствия ("without no warranty"), например, в GNU GPL, MIT и т.д.

В любом случае, ознакомиться с основными, наиболее распространёнными, разрешениями имеет смысл, но от сомнительного использования пользователей они не остановят.